# Stripe | how to trigger inovice.paymnet_failed web hook in test mood

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, testcase

I am playing with stripe subscription for recurring payments, I need to update my system database if any invoice goes to fail. For this I used `invoice.payment_failed` webhook event.

I used stripe given test card number 4000000000000341 for this purpose, but it's not triggering `invoice.payment_failed` event.

Please help it's become very painful form me. Thanks in advance

Comment: If I recall correctly (been a while since I've developed an app that uses Stripe) it takes some time for the invoice to be sent for payment, so the invoice.payment_failed is only triggered later (I think it takes an hour, but I could be wrong).

Comment: i wait one hour too, invoice.payment_failed does not called? what you mean by correctly use stripe? can you Elaborate this cycle please?

Comment: I didn't say anything about using Stripe correctly, only about whether I remember correctly. You can try looking at the events/logs in the developers section [https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/developers](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/developers) and see if the payment failed, or maybe if the webhook was called or if there was an error. Otherwise you can contact Stripe's support team, they were quite helpful back when I was developing an app with Stripe.

Comment: stripe trigger invoice.payment_failed
use this command to run that event in CLI